# How does one find the /dev/... path for an Apple MacBook Pro (t2linux) keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

I am trying to get the very cool [dual function keys](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/dual-function-keys) plugin working on my Ubuntu 20.04 MacBook Pro (2020 16", Model 16.1) system. In order to do that I need to set an environment variable (`DEVNODE`) to the path of the keyboard (`/dev/???`). What would that path be?

I do see posts using something like `/dev/input/byId` which raises the question: how do I find the id for my keyboard?